# any remote desktop client that works on wifi network?

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm pretty clear, im thinking something like chromecast... i mean stream remote desktop from the wifi, I know that I can do that from the client that comes by default in Windows, but I've tried several times and does not work

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you wanting something that displays your desktop to others on your local network? or are you looking for something that allows you to access other desktops on the wifi network?

Answer (score 1):

Any of them.

Remote software, whether it is Remote Desktop, VNC, TeamView or Remote Amdin all work based off networking and permissions.

If you are not able to remote a computer, you need to verify the machine can accept remote connections, and that the two computers can see each other over the network.